# JSON object Ignore null

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Im kinda new to MuleSoft and DataWeave and im trying to make a JSON Object with only not null values from another JSON object.

Let's say this is my JSON array :

```
{
    str1 : "String 1",
    str2 : "String 2",
    str3 : null,
    str4 : "String 4",
}
```

I want to make a copy of that JSON array but without str3, so result should looks like this :

```
{
    str1 : "String 1",
    str2 : "String 2",
    str4 : "String 4",
}
```

Anyone can help me out with this ? or atleast lead me to the solutions ?

Regards

Comment: That is not a JSON array, it is a JSON object. And the keys are missing quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's yet another way:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var o = {
    str1 : "String 1",
    str2 : "String 2",
    str3 : null,
    str4 : "String 4",
}
---
o filterObject $ != null
```

Here's the filterObject [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-filterobject)

Pick the one you like :)

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 possible approaches:

Using the writer property `skipNullOn` as mentioned [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats-json#properties)

```
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
payload
```

Programatically with an if condition (this is for field by field mapping)

```
var b = null
---
{
    a: 1,
    (b: b) if b != null,
    c: 3
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For an object you can transform all the attributes that are not null:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload mapObject (($$): $ ) if (!($ == null))
```